# spring security custom session timeout stuck in infinite loop

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I am trying to implement a custom session timeout handler using spring security to add a dynamic parameter onto the redirect url and I have a problem where I am getting into an infinite loop but I don't know why. I was wondering if someone could enlighten me on this?

```
<http use-expressions="true" auto-config="false" entry-point-ref="loginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint">    
    <!-- custom filters -->
    <custom-filter position="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" ref="twoFactorAuthenticationFilter" />      
    <custom-filter after="SECURITY_CONTEXT_FILTER" ref="securityLoggingFilter"/>
     <custom-filter before="SESSION_MANAGEMENT_FILTER" ref="sessionManagementFilter" />

    <!-- session management -->     
    <session-management session-fixation-protection="none" />

    <!-- error handlers -->
    <access-denied-handler error-page="/accessDenied.htm"/>             

    <!-- logout --> 
    <logout             
        invalidate-session="false" 
        delete-cookies="JSESSIONID" 
        success-handler-ref="customUrlLogoutSuccessHandler"/>


    <!-- authorize pages -->    
    <intercept-url pattern="/home.htm" access="isAuthenticated()" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/shortsAndOvers.htm" access="isAuthenticated()" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/shortsAndOversDaily.htm" access="isAuthenticated()" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/birtpage.htm" access="isAuthenticated()" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/reports/show.htm" access="isAuthenticated()" />    

</http> 

<beans:bean id="sessionManagementFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter">
    <beans:constructor-arg name="securityContextRepository" ref="httpSessionSecurityContextRepository" />
    <beans:property name="invalidSessionStrategy" ref="customSimpleRedirectInvalidSessionStrategy" />
</beans:bean>   

<beans:bean id="customSimpleRedirectInvalidSessionStrategy" class="com.myer.reporting.security.CustomSimpleRedirectInvalidSessionStrategy">
  <beans:constructor-arg name="invalidSessionUrl" value="/sessionExpired.htm" />
  <beans:property name="createNewSession" value="false" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="httpSessionSecurityContextRepository" class="org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository"/>
```

So far so good. When I get a session timeout the code in CustomSimpleRedirectInvalidSessionStrategy.onInvalidSessionDetected is called....

```
public CustomSimpleRedirectInvalidSessionStrategy(String invalidSessionUrl) {
    Assert.isTrue(UrlUtils.isValidRedirectUrl(invalidSessionUrl), "url must start with '/' or with 'http(s)'");
    this.destinationUrl = invalidSessionUrl;
}
public void onInvalidSessionDetected(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    logger.debug("Starting new session (if required) and redirecting to '" + destinationUrl + "'");
        SecurityContext securityContext = SecurityContextHolder.getContext();
        String store = null;
        ReportingManagerUser user = null;
        if (securityContext != null){
            Authentication authentication = securityContext.getAuthentication();

            if (authentication!=null && !(authentication instanceof AnonymousAuthenticationToken)){
                user = (ReportingManagerUser)authentication.getPrincipal();
                if (user!=null){
                    store = user.getStore();
                }                   
            }
        }

        String amendedTargetUrl = null;
        if (user !=null && user.isLoggedInWithSiteId()){
            amendedTargetUrl = 
                    destinationUrl.concat(
                    ParamConstants.PARAM_PREFIX + 
                    ParamConstants.PARAM_SITE_ID + 
                    ParamConstants.PARAM_EQ 
                    + store);
        }else{
            amendedTargetUrl = destinationUrl;              
        } 

    if (createNewSession) {
        request.getSession();
    }
    redirectStrategy.sendRedirect(request, response, amendedTargetUrl);
}
```

And the code is executed properly but even after the redirect the code just keeps falling into the onInvalidSessionDetected method instead of actually redirecting to what I've configured in the invalidSessionUrl property.

I don't really get it.

thanks in advance

Comment: Most likely the JSESSIONID cookie isn't being deleted when you log out. As the docs mention [this isn't guaranteed to work](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#ns-session-mgmt). Check it without your own handler included to see if that works. Also, it's normal to invalidate the session when you logout. Removing the cookie and leaving the session intact doesn't really make much sense.

Comment: Thanks for that tip. I solved it by adding security = none to the redirect url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Silly mistake. I did not have security excluded on the redirect url. So it was trying to validation the jsession for that page and failing each time. Lol